# 24-bit audio sample into int32 array (little-endian WAV file)

Tags: python, audio, numpy, int, endianness

I read a 24-bit mono audio .wav file into an array of type `<i4` (`<i3` doesn't exist)

```
data = numpy.fromfile(fid, dtype=`<i4`, count=size//3)
```

**What should I do in order to get the audio samples properly ?** Should I swap bytes order of something like this, how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the data into a numpy array of `uint8`, then add the 0 to each sample by using `reshape` and `hstack`;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
```

I'm using a generated sequence here as an example.

```
In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3]*10, dtype=np.uint8)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2,
       3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8)

In [4]: a = a.reshape((-1,3))
```

Reshape allows you to group the samples:

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

Make the zeros that have to be added.

```
In [6]: b = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((-1,1))

In [7]: b
Out[7]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Now we add the zeroes. Assuming you're using a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system, the added zero goes at the front, to scale the data.

(I hope I got this endianness stuff right. If the sample now sounds very faint, I got it wrong and you need to use `(a,b)` instead of `(b,a)`)

```
In [8]: c = np.hstack((b, a))

In [9]: c
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

Reshape it back.

```
In [10]: c.reshape((1,-1))
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,
        2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

Convert to bytes:

```
In [11]: bytearray(c.reshape((1,-1)))
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x01\x02\x03')
```

Now you have 4-byte samples.

Comment: I know, that's precisely what I want to understand: how can I swap the bytes order in order to read my 3 bytes (24 bits) into a int32 array...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for reading 24 bits files (thanks to Warren Weckesser's gist https://gist.github.com/WarrenWeckesser/7461781) :

```
data = numpy.fromfile(fid, dtype='u1', count=size) # first read byte per byte

a = numpy.empty((len(data)/3, 4), dtype=`u1`)
a[:, :3] = data.reshape((-1, 3))
a[:, 3:] = (a[:, 3 - 1:3] >> 7) * 255
data = a.view('<i4').reshape(a.shape[:-1])
```

This can be directly inserted in `def _read_data_chunk(fid, noc, bits):`  (`scipy\io\wavfile.py`).